# Loop through Google Sheet

Tags: loops, google-apps-script

I know enough to be dangerous. But not enough for some things. I have cobbled this script together and it works. Currently this checks if a CSV file is in a specific folder, if so, creates a tab and imports the data into that tab. But, I have like 50 offices and are expanding. So rather than repeat the function 50 times, I want to read the list of offices from the Google Sheet and loop through the results replacing the "DTMadisonData" portion. Can anyone help me?

```
var fSource = DriveApp.getFolderById('XXXXXXXfK70bknfK1lY4NJNZxxwgvLUu'); 
  // reports_folder_id = id of folder where csv reports are saved

var fi = fSource.getFilesByName('DTMadisonData.csv'); 
      // latest report file

    if ( fi.hasNext() ) { // proceed if "DTMadisonData.csv" file exists in the reports folder
    /*
    Check if Sheet exists, if not create it
    */  

      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
       var mysheet = "MadisonDTData";

       if (ss.getSheetByName(mysheet ) == null){
           ss.insertSheet('MadisonDTData');
           var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();


        }  
      var file = fi.next();
    var csv = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
    var csvData = CSVToArray(csv); // see below for CSVToArray function

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('DTMadisonData');

      // loop through csv data array and insert (append) as rows into 'DTMadisonData' sheet
    for ( var i=0, lenCsv=csvData.length; i<lenCsv; i++ ) {
      sheet.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, csvData[i].length).setValues(new Array(csvData[i]));
    }
      }  

    };


    // http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1504-Ask-Ben-Parsing-CSV-Strings-With-Javascript-Exec-Regular-Expression-Command.htm
    // This will parse a delimited string into an array of
    // arrays. The default delimiter is the comma, but this
    // can be overriden in the second argument.




    function CSVToArray( strData, strDelimiter ) {
    // Check to see if the delimiter is defined. If not,
    // then default to COMMA.
    strDelimiter = (strDelimiter || ",");

    // Create a regular expression to parse the CSV values.
    var objPattern = new RegExp(
    (
      // Delimiters.
        "(\\" + strDelimiter + "|\\r?\\n|\\r|^)" +

        // Quoted fields.
        "(?:\"([^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*)\"|" +

        // Standard fields.
        "([^\"\\" + strDelimiter + "\\r\\n]*))"
      ),
      "gi"
    );

    // Create an array to hold our data. Give the array
    // a default empty first row.
    var arrData = [[]];

    // Create an array to hold our individual pattern
    // matching groups.
    var arrMatches = null;

    // Keep looping over the regular expression matches
    // until we can no longer find a match.
    while (arrMatches = objPattern.exec( strData )){

    // Get the delimiter that was found.
    var strMatchedDelimiter = arrMatches[ 1 ];

    // Check to see if the given delimiter has a length
    // (is not the start of string) and if it matches
    // field delimiter. If id does not, then we know
    // that this delimiter is a row delimiter.
    if (
      strMatchedDelimiter.length &&
      (strMatchedDelimiter != strDelimiter)
    ){

      // Since we have reached a new row of data,
      // add an empty row to our data array.
      arrData.push( [] );

    }

    // Now that we have our delimiter out of the way,
    // let's check to see which kind of value we
    // captured (quoted or unquoted).
    if (arrMatches[ 2 ]){

      // We found a quoted value. When we capture
      // this value, unescape any double quotes.
      var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 2 ].replace(
        new RegExp( "\"\"", "g" ),
        "\""
      );

    } else {

      // We found a non-quoted value.
      var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 3 ];

    }

    // Now that we have our value string, let's add
    // it to the data array.
    arrData[ arrData.length - 1 ].push( strMatchedValue );
    }

    // Return the parsed data.
    return( arrData );
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I was able to work it out with another script I dug up!

```
function importCSVFromGoogleDrive() {
var fSource = DriveApp.getFolderById('XXXXXXXXX0bknfK1lY4NJNZxxwgvLUu'); 
  // reports_folder_id = id of folder where csv reports are saved


  //var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet('OfficeList');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("OfficeList"));


   var startRow = 1;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 50;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A1:A50
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 1)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var officeName = row[0];  // First column
   var fi = fSource.getFilesByName(officeName + ".csv"); 
  // latest report file

if ( fi.hasNext() ) { // proceed if "officeName.csv" file exists in the reports folder

/*
Check if Sheet exists, if not create it
*/  

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var mysheet = officeName;

   if (ss.getSheetByName(mysheet ) == null){
       ss.insertSheet(officeName);
       var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();


    }  

var file = fi.next();
var csv = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
var csvData = CSVToArray(csv); // see below for CSVToArray function

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(officeName);

  // loop through csv data array and insert (append) as rows into 'SpoonerData' sheet
for ( var i=0, lenCsv=csvData.length; i<lenCsv; i++ ) {
  sheet.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, csvData[i].length).setValues(new Array(csvData[i]));
}
  }

  }
};
```